# Easiest way to substitute characters in the string

Tags: python

Suppose I have a main form named "`main_form`" and I have few more forms name like "`w_main_form`","`g_main_form`" etc etc which are based on "`main_form`" and they vary according to the '`category`'.

Now is there any easy way to *generate* names of derived forms and how to call them.

Suppose the category is "`iron`" then the form name should be "`w_main_form`" and when the category is "`coal`" the form name should be "`g_main_form`".

Comment: Suppose the category is "iron" then the form name should be "w_main_form" and when the category is "coal" the form name should be "g_main_form"?Can you help now?

Comment: What determines the form name for a category? If it can't be computed then use a dictionary to look it up. Not sure what you mean by "how to call them" -- are they something callable, like `w_main_form()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> main_name = "main_form"
>>> derived_names = []
>>> for prefix in ["w_", "g_"]:
    derived_names.append("%s%s" % (prefix, main_name))


>>> derived_names
['w_main_form', 'g_main_form']
```

Or, with list comprehensions (my preferred method):

```
>>> derived_names = ["%s%s" % (prefix, main_name) for prefix in ["w_", "g_"]]
>>> derived_names
['w_main_form', 'g_main_form']
```

In general, so you can apply the same principle yourself, you want to think of the transform you want to do in terms of a function, `f(main_name, data)`, and the `data` to provide to it. In this case, the operation was "prepend" (which I implemented with `"%s%s" % (prefix, main_name)`) and the data was all the prefixes.

EDIT: Yes.

```
>>> category_to_prefix = {'iron': 'w_', 'coal': 'g_'}
>>> def category_to_form_name(category):
    return '%s%s' % (category_to_prefix.get(category,""), 'main_form')

>>> category_to_form_name('iron')
'w_main_form'
>>> category_to_form_name('coal')
'g_main_form'
>>> category_to_form_name(None)
'main_form'
```

Please upvote and accept the answer (click the up arrow and the green checkmark) if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Suppose the category is "iron" then the form name should be "w_main_form" and when the category is "coal" the form name should be "g_main_form"?Can you help now?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what your comment stated ..

```
def generate_Name(base, category):
    if category == 'iron':
        derived_name = 'w_'+base
    elif category == 'coal':
        derived_name = 'g_'+base

    return derived_name


iron_form = generate_Name('main_form', 'iron')
coal_form = generate_Name('main_form', 'coal')

print iron_form
print coal_form
```

gives

```
w_main_form
g_main_form
```

Comment: @Claudiu agreed! .. I'll leave this as a simple literal alternative which is functional (but not as nice as using a dictionary :)

Comment: and how can I call these generated name?Like I have to call "w_main_form("argument1","argument2")".How to do that.Also I don't want to modify "w_main_form()".So is there anyway I can achieve that without touching my existing forms?

Comment: @Levon what variable names are you asking about?

Comment: @RajatSaxena you were asking about how to "call these generated names" .. so I was wondering if you were referring to variable names for each of the generated names.